# Change text of toolbar button for fontsizeselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

I have this kind of toolbar for tinyMCE.

[image]

As you can see I am using only Icons for all the buttons. But the button to change the font size contains the text "Font Sizes". How I can change it so that it only show the selected size e.g. "**12px**" by default.

I have actually tried this code:

```
setup : function(ed)
  {
    ed.on('init', function() 
    {
        this.execCommand("fontSize", false, "12px");
    });
  }
```

On page load I can see the text "**12px**" for font size button. But as soon as the tinyMCE text area is clicked the text of button changes back to "**Font Sizes**"

Is it somehow possible to totally skip this text "**Font Sizes**"